# Start a snapshot replication using C# or T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, replication, snapshot

I have a database that I process for quite some time, once the processing is done I would like to "clone" the database to another database. Currently I'm doing this using a timed Snapshot replication using SQL Server.

However.. what I really would like to do is to start the replication once the processing is done.. is there anyway possible to do this?

Comment: How are you 'processing' the database? SSIS or SSAS? Or T-SQL?

Comment: Im currently having a C# application that pulls down data from an external source and populates and normalizes this data and stores it in the database, and the SQL is generated by EntityFramework.

Comment: Solved it using:
sp_startpublication_snapshot @publication=[name of publication] or in C#
EntityFrameworkDataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("sp_startpublication_snapshot @publication='{0}'", publicationname));